# How would a Jetty Servlet detect a request from a LocalConnector?

Tags: servlets, jetty, jetty-9

I want to use

```
LocalConnector.getResponses( "POST /myservlet/SpecialRequest HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-Length: x\r\n\r\n<content>\r\n\r\n" );
```

to send special requests to servlets from within my application (uses embedded Jetty server).  How can the Servlet detect that the request isfrom a LocalConnector instead of an external source?

The doPost method only has a HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects as parameters.

Using Jetty 9.2.4 and Servlet 3.1 APIs.

Comment: Are there no Jetty experts on this forum?  Both questions I asked where, in my opinion, valid hard questions and I get no views and no votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined there is no way to identify the Connector but looking inside the request, there are a few 0.0.0.0 and port 0 values which I'm confident wouldn't be the case from any external request (even localhost requests show up as 127.0.0.1).

```
LocalAddr = 0.0.0.0
LocalName = 0.0.0.0
LocalPort = 0
ServerName = <a real ip>
ServerPort = 80
RemoteAddr = 0.0.0.0
RemoteHost = 0.0.0.0
```

The ServerName and ServerPort are bogus - I don't have a Connector on port 80 and the request log shows

```
0.0.0.0 - - [21/Nov/2014:11:20:56 -0500] "POST /myservlet/SpecialRequest HTTP/1.0" - 0 "-" "-" "-"
```

which doesn't match the ServerName.

Conclusion: if LocalAddr and RemoteAddr are 0.0.0.0, request is internal from the LocalConnector.

Hope this answer helps the next person - and thanks to the one who posted the other LocalConnector question which pointed me to that feature!

Comment: Hope you aren't using LocalConnector in production or standalone distribution.  As your webapp wouldn't be able to access that class.

Comment: LocalConnector is also an internal testing class that Jetty uses itself.  It can (and often does) change from release to release.

Comment: Yes @JoakimErdfelt, I'm using it in production code and it seems to work fine.  There were no warnings in the documentation. All my servlets are embedded - no web apps.  I have an external force that tells me to modify (administer) my running servlets. I then use the LocalConnector to send a secure message to the affected servlet. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Nope, as you are using it in embedded mode, you are pretty much avoiding the classloader isolation that the standard / standalone distribution uses (which is what would have given you problems)